# Is having a single column table in SQL Server considered a bad practice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

A coworker and myself stumbled upon a newly acquired database schema with multiple tables that seem to only have one column. One table seems to be some sort of type, and the another for some sort of frequency, etc. We are only dealing with a schema here so there's no actual data to go by.

We were thinking it over, and we can't really wrap our head around the need, or the type of information that should, "*in best practice*", use only a single column.

Through my education, we were taught there should always be some sort of Note, Time Stamp, Description or type of information associated with each primary key.

Through a couple google searches I find that a lot of sites mention only how this behavior can affect primary key practices, but not information in general.

So to reiterate my question: **Is it considered a bad practice to design tables with only a single column? And how can this actually be beneficial to only have said single column? Are there any industry examples you can think of?**

Comment: Restricting values in another table via foreign key.

Comment: Unfortunately, the identities of the creators seems to be kind of an anomaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every table that I create has the following columns:

- Primary key (generally a number and named after the table is `Id` after it).
- CreatedAt
- CreatedBy
- CreatedOn (the server where the row was created)

One use for a single column table is to effectively implement a check constraint where the code can dynamically validate values.  I would typically implement this using a reference table with a proper foreign key relationships and the above columns.

Another instance would be a number table, which just stores integer values.

In general, I would say that it isn't a good idea.  There may be specific cases such as a number table where it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, that depends on the use of this tables.

If you have a lot of them, its probably wrong. I can think of a few uses of a single column table , they can be used as `derived tables` to generate ID's, sequences , dates(which probably be more useful with more then 1 column to specify month,year..) ETC but I believe they do have a purpose.

In general, its always better to have more then one column, some sort of key column of an ID or a date to the table so it will mean something.

If its bad practice? I believe so, always better to have more information on a table, unless its a specific table used for a specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, no suprise.

One more case for one-column table I saw was an anchor table for the entity where every attribute (name, date, etc) proved to be time dependent, or version dependent. So they are organized as a number of extension history/version tables holding set of some way grouped attributes where every such extension group is optional.

Answer (score 1):

If that column is not it's primary key than it's definitely bad practice.

But if it is primary key and either foreign key to some other table or other table has foreign key relation with this, it can be part of normalization of schema.

You can get rid of null columns by creating two column table (ID,PREVIOUSLY_NULLABLE_COLLUMN) instead of nullable column (or if you have columns ID,A,B,C where A and B both should be not null or null and C is independently optional, you will have tables (ID),(ID,A,B), (ID,C)).

If original table only had nullable columns and primary key, you will end with one column table and bunch of "column" tables.

This approach makes sense if you really achieve some higher NF (i don't remember which one) or if you have lot of optional columns.